# Comment editing boxes

Tags: feature-request, comment, css

It would be awesome if the textarea elements one uses to create/edit comments on M.SE were larger and allowed for more characters. The ones on MO are perfect, for example.

(Why do I want this? Well, I just wrote/edited a longish comment and doing it without a preview in 3 lines is a bit annoying Also, I had things like T(\mathcal U(\mathfrak g)), which get counted by-the-character!)

Comment: The comment textareas on MO are taller (nine rows instead of 5em), but they still only allow 600 characters.

Comment: In some browsers you can manually change the dimensions of textareas. In chrome, you can drag the lower right hand corner of the comment box to make it larger/smaller.

Comment: I just noticed that a "better way" to edit a comment is to do the work in an answer box, and then copy it into the comment field once I'm happy with it.  That way you can see the math preview as well.  The main glitch is that the site seems to auto-save the answer box, so you have to remember to explicitly discard it.  (Is there any reason not to edit comments this way?)  Also, it's too painful to contemplate doing this on a phone or tablet.